# How to repair fonts for Perl/Tk (14.04)

Tags: fonts, perl, antialiasing

With Ubuntu 14. 04 I have Perl 5.18.2 for x86_64-Linux-gnu-thread-multi on my laptop which is nice, but after installing `Perl/Tk-804.032` from CPAN I seem to only get non-antialiased fonts (scaled bitmaps?) when I start Perl/Tk scripts that looked OK on Ubuntu 12.04:

[image]

Any suggestions how to repair the fonts or to investigate the problem are appreciated.

Comment: Could you show as a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: @terdon, i would like to edit and insert a png of Tk::FontDialog but don't have the 'reputation' to do so i was told

Comment: Yes, you need 10 reputation to post images. That's there to blovk SPAM. Just upload your image to a free service like http://imgur.com and [edit]your question to add a link to it. Someone will edit the image  in for you.

Comment: @terdon, here we go [link](http://imgur.com/McSWnBI)

Comment: Have you considered using `Gtk2` instead? I think that's the best you can do with Tk.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a while I think I found the cause of my Perl-Tk fonts problem: a reinstallation of Ubuntu 14.04 plus Perl-Tk made the problem disappear.

So why did it appear in first place?

One thing that very likely caused problems in the old installation was that at one point I changed the user name and the name of the home directory (!) using the `bash` command `usermod`.

Observing that CPAN was still sticking to the old (now wrong) home directory when I installed Perl packages, I think this had to mean troubles in unpredictable cases.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've met the requirements which are described in README.linux, which comes with the distribution. I guess that you did not have libXft-devel installed and thus it was build without support for Xft (true type fonts etc).

Comment: 'aptitude search' tells me the required libs are installed or virtually there :
i   libx11-dev
i   libfreetype6-dev
i   libxft-dev
v   libpng-dev
v   libz-dev
i   libjpeg-dev

Comment: Hm, the pictures look for me like it was not build with Xft. Do you still have the build log? Can you make a `grep -i xft` over the build log or the generated Makefile?

Comment: Captured the log of a forced Tk-rebuild and searched the makefile. Didn't discover a hint that anything went wrong with Xft. But i agree that 'xft' seems the most likely problem. Don't have the time to dig deeper right now, maybe some time later.